# overloaded bool conversion and dereference object pointer

Tags: c++, object, pointers

```
class D{
    bool var;
public:
    D(bool x): var(x) {}
    operator bool(){return var;}
};

int main() {
    D* temp1 = new D(false);
    cout << *temp1;  //0

    D* temp2 = new D(true);
    cout << *temp2;  //1
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to overload bool conversion for object D. Then I discover that there is a relation between the overloaded bool conversion and the value when dereferencing an object pointer.

I initialize 2 object with difference values. When I try to dereference the pointer, I see that they return the same value as that of overloaded bool conversion.
What is the relation between overloaded bool conversion and dereferencing an object pointer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're printing the result of converting your `D` objects to `bool`:

- Dreferencing a `D*` give you a value of type `D`.
- When you write `cout << *temp1`, the language looks for an `operator<<` overload that takes a `std::ostream` as its left-hand operand and an object of the type of `D` as its right-hand operand.

  - There is no such overload, but there *is* an overload that takes a right-hand operand of type `bool`.
  - Since a `D` can be implicitly converted to `bool` thanks to its `operator bool`, `std::ostream::operator<<(bool)` is chosen as the best `<<` operator overload in this situation.

That particular operator inserts `0` into the `std::ostream` for `false` values and inserts `1` for `true` values (unless the `std::boolalpha` manipulator has previously been applied to the stream).  Thus, since `static_cast<bool>(*temp1)` is `false`, `cout << *temp1` prints `0` and since `static_cast<bool>(*temp2)` is `true` `cout << *temp2` prints `1`.

Comment: The conversion from D datatype to bool is due to the implementation of class iostream or the mechanism of compiler ?

Comment: Kind of both?  It's due to standard overload resolution rules.  If the compiler can't find an exact match for a function call it will consider up to one user-defined conversion.  The standard library just happens to have an `operator<<` overload that accepts a `std::ostream` and a `bool` that's used for printing `bool`s, and that happens to be the best match in this case.  You could write your own `operator<<(std::ostream&, const D&)` to do whatever you want and that would [get selected as a better match](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77a6d9e3da8fbddc).

Answer (score 1):

> What is the relation between overloaded bool conversion and dereferencing an object pointer?

When you indirect through the object pointer, the result is an lvalue to the object. When you define an implicit conversion operator to bool, that object is convertible to bool. That's what's happening: You're using the conversion operator, and the result of the conversion is passed as an argument to the stream insertion operator.